# How to find out what causes excessiv incoming traffic?

Tags: linux, centos, traffic

On a simple webserver configuration (CentOS 7) with nginx/apache (reverse proxy setup) I have a lot of incoming traffic on one NIC (eth0).

**1. Is there a way to find out what causes it or "where it arrives"?**

There are no FTP, Mail or DB services running. The DB (MongoDB and MySQL) are on different servers and the connection is on a different NIC (eth1).

eth0 is public while eth1 is connected to a private switch with no external access. There is a firewall in place and for eth0 only the ports 80, 443 and 22 are open. Fail2ban bans a few hundred IPs a day (trying to login via ssh), but that's similar to my other servers.

**2. If someone is sending arbitrary data to any arbitrary port, i. e. 555, which the firewall should block, does vnstat still register all the data or just the size of the headers and the rest is rejected?**

I couldn't find any suspicious files on the server. The website doesn't offer any upload mechanism.

I am recording the traffic with vnstat. The last 24h looked like this:

```
 h  rx (MiB)   tx (MiB)      h  rx (MiB)   tx (MiB)      h  rx (MiB)   tx (MiB) 
13    4045.50    6184.14    21    2683.89    4172.90    05    1652.97    1226.57
14    3210.47    4768.60    22    2923.88    3303.21    06    1473.85    1686.85
15    3310.31    5880.16    23    1850.60    1909.20    07    1506.75    3185.17
16    3697.05    5347.17    00    1924.60    1544.29    08    2412.61    3972.74
17    2656.44    4270.50    01    3103.59    2019.04    09    2602.51    5185.76
18    1889.34    4209.50    02    1890.90    1014.04    10    3353.67    6353.20
19    1679.18    5564.48    03    2502.21    1197.43    11    1792.24    6760.07
20    2661.70   14444.84    04    2187.66    1089.72    12     571.53    1852.97
```

At night, in this case between midnight and 5 am (UTC) the incoming traffic even exceeds the outgoing traffic, what doesn't make much sense to me - it's still just a website.

tcpdump shows a lot of action on port 443 and far less on port 80, but the length is almost always 0. Sometimes there are a few bytes but that doesn't make up for a few gigs an hour. There's almost nothing going on on port 22.

```
tcpdump -l -n -i eth0 dst port 443 and inbound

12:40:50.682931 IP 1.2.3.4.13416 > 1.2.3.4.http: 
Flags [.], ack 173761, win 428, options [nop,nop,TS val 223856478 ecr 281640876], length 0
```

I would like to find out the source or reason for this traffic and lock it out, somehow.

Comment: So is this a front end Nginx server listening on eth0 that proxies to back-end Apache server(s)? What is eth1 is used for? Anything in Nginx access logs? Do you see any high hits from unknown IPs with `cat /var/log/nginx/access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head`

Comment: nginx is acting as reverse proxy for apache, serving static content while apache is handling php. eth1 is in an internal network on a dedicated switch with sql and mongo servers, firewalled and allowing only connections between these servers. There are some hits in the thousands from unknown IPs, growing with a rate of ~20 hits/minute. I don't think that's considerably high. The log doesn't show any suspicious entries as far as I can tell. Lot of bots, but they should raise the outgoing, not the incoming traffic.